# Datatables TypeError: c is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I try to use jQuery DataTables but I get the error

> TypeError: c is undefined

I don't know what is wrong with my code as I can see the JSON correctly retrieve and is in the correct format too but I don't know what is wrong with it that I get the above error.

My JSON :

```
{"Data":[{"LOGIN":10184},{"LOGIN":10214},{"LOGIN":10180},{"LOGIN":10187},{"LOGIN":10179},{"LOGIN":10280},{"LOGIN":201},{"LOGIN":10238},{"LOGIN":10296},{"LOGIN":10312}]}
```

and my DataTables code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tablename').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "type": "POST",
        "url": "https://test.com/api/db/select",
        "data": function ( json ) {  return JSON.stringify( { "Sql": 12 } );},
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "dataType": "json",
        "processData": true,
            beforeSend : function(xhr){
                        var access_token = sessionStorage.getItem('access_token');
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
            }
        },
        "dataSrc": "Data",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "LOGIN" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: I Suppose you are using the minified js of the plugin, if you use the non-minified one, you'll get more useful information... there is no "c" variable in your code...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**`dataSrc`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) is a special dataTables ajax option, that should be included inside the ajax object :

```
"ajax": {
    "dataSrc": "Data", //<--- place dataSrc here instead
    "type": "POST",
    ...
}
```

You have placed it outside ajax, and by that dataTables have no idea what source to use (besides blindly trying the ajax response) or where `LOGIN` belongs.

Answer (score 116):

Check whether you have added

```
<thead></thead>

<tbody></tbody>
```

I've resolved this problem by adding those.

So basically the structure must be like:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 19):

Sometime, This type issue arrives by fixing mismatched / unequal columns with HTML and datatables columns.

```
"columns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        {"orderable": false, "width":"2%"},
    ],
```

Above javascript defined 4 columns and HTML having 5 columns

```
<tr>
   <td>A</td>
   <td>B</td>
   <td>C</td>
   <td>D</td>
   <td>E</td>
</tr>
```

Hence you will have to fix / equal both side HTMl and Datatable configuration.

```
"columns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null, //Added New
        {"orderable": false, "width":"2%"},
    ],
```

Answer (score 5):

in my case, i had to remove colspan attribute from a th  inside thead  and get rid of the error ;(

Answer (score 2):

In my case, missing aaData in sever side return result.

```
//Javascript
$('#table').DataTable({
        sAjaxSource: '/load',
        aoColumns: [
         ...
        ],
});
//server side(in Rails)
render json: {'aaData'=>data}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got the same error because I used the *ajax.dataSrc( data )* function to manipulate the data. But after that i forgot to return the data.

```
"dataSrc": function ( json ) {
  for ( var i=0, ien=json.data.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
      //somethings...
  }
  return json.data;// I forgot this line, then i got the error "TypeError: c is undefined"
}
```

After a few minutes, I checked the documentation of the ajax.dataSrc function and I noticed that I did not have the return:

***Returns: array***. Array of data that DataTables is to use to draw the table

I hope you do not have the same distraction...

Answer (score 1):

In my case *th* and *td* , count is not equal due do colspan, removed colspan and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the number of column in `<thead>` tag is different than the number of column in `<tbody>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my front-end: `ajax: { dataSrc: "data" }` was OK, but on server-side I returned object where first letter was Upper `return Json(new { Data = model });`

Answer (score 0):

Another day, another solution - this time **caused by a style sheet**!

After spending hours reducing a gigantic web page to the raw charts code, I found that this error shows (for pie charts) when CSS rules for fonts in the stylesheet contain the `calc` function.

In our style sheet, this line of code:

```
html {
  font-size: calc(12px + 5%);
}
```

...broke the chart.  We needed this because our webfont wasn't resizing smoothly and needed a size slightly larger than 12px but smaller than 13px, and this trick forced a better resize.

Overwriting the style rule on the chart widget directly solved the issue:

## CSS

```
html {
  font-size: calc(12px + 5%);
}
.widget {
   font-size: 12px /* Replace the above rule */;
}
```

## JS

```
var GoogleChart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Chart1'));
```

## HTML

```
<div id="Chart1" class="widget"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check followings

`<td></td>` -- check count

`<th></th>` -- check count

check `<tbody>` and `<thead>` - opening and closing